# How create and populate three columns on Android

Tags: android, layout

I need populate three columns in Android activity with dynamic data. How  can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, your current task can be achieved by doing the below steps.

1. Create a standalone linear layout with horizontal orientation and add three TextView views.
2. In the target layout file, create a ListView with the above created layout.
3. Bind the listview layout with a data adapter and map the fields to the textview.

[This example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) should get you started and add that background to achieve the above goals.